# Loop Through Files VBA

Tags: excel, vba

i'm trying to loop through all the files in the folder while copying them into the workbook i'm running the macro, the copy/pasting is already done, what i'm missing is the loop so i can automate this process, i already worked in my code but it does nothing.

```
    Option Explicit
Sub DailyTrans_MDM()
Dim vFile As Variant
Dim folderPath As String
Dim filePath As String
Dim wbCopyTo As Workbook
Dim wsCopyTo As Worksheet
Dim wbCopyFrom  As Workbook
Dim wsCopyFrom As Worksheet

folderPath = (filePath & "*.xl*")
vFile = Dir(folderPath & "*.xl*")
Do While vFile <> ""

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wbCopyTo = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsCopyTo = ActiveSheet
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Set wbCopyFrom = Workbooks.Open(vFile)
Set wsCopyFrom = wbCopyFrom.Worksheets("ReporteCifrasControl")

'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
wsCopyFrom.Range("A2:M" & wsCopyFrom.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row).Copy
wsCopyTo.Range("A" & wsCopyTo.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
wbCopyFrom.Close SaveChanges:=False


vFile = Dir
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Hope you can help me, please

Comment: Add `vFile  = Dir` before the `Loop`. Also `Dir` will never return a boolean so you can remove the `If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then`.

Comment: @BigBen thank you for your quick answer but it still does nothing :| updated the code with your advice.

Comment: Other notes: `Set wbCopyTo = ActiveWorkbook` and `Set wsCopyTo = ActiveSheet` - these should be outside the loop.

Comment: Looks like you're concatenating `"*.xl*"` to the path *twice*... that's problematic. `folderPath = (filePath & "*.xl*")` and then `vFile = Dir(folderPath & "*.xl*")`. That concatenation should only happen once, probably within `Dir`.

Comment: Thank you, the problem is fixed now i have to add the Application.FileDialog so i can pick the folder of the files i want to copy @BigBen

Comment: note that this is not meant to be a code-writing site. Should be pretty straightforward for you to do that yourself :-)

Comment: @BigBen yeah, it was just a comment i added, sorry.